# Limit items display in Listview and display the continuous image

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

May I know how to limit the numbers of items display in ListView for Xamarin.Forms?
for example at first display 10 items, then after that display another 10 items.

Because I want to prevent crash when the image is load in Listview.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the number of items in your list to (for example) 10 items. Then you have to subscribe to the `ItemAppearing` event of the `ListView`.

In this event you can check if the last item is appearing. In this case: Just load more items to the list. Either you add it directly in the code behinde of the page or you bind to an `ObservableCollection` in a ViewModel.

```
listview.ItemAppearing += (sender, e) => 
{
    // Check if you reach the bottom
    if(e.Item == lastitem)
    {
        // load more items
    }
};
```

You can find a full example on [this blog entry from James Montemagno](http://motzcod.es/post/107620279512/load-more-items-at-end-of-listview-in).

When you have truble with loading images and memory, take a look at [FFImageLoading on GitHub](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading). This is a brilliant nuget package to load images fast and to cache them.